# iPhone iPad page formatting issue

Tags: html, iphone, css, ipad

I am working on this site and have found that on every browser the page centers ok, but on an iPad the page renders hard up against the left side of the screen. This is also the case on an iPhone and Galaxy. Also the "Add This" buttons do not appear on mobile devices but work OK in all browsers on DT/NB.

Browser view:
[image]

iPad mini view:
[image]

As example, the header area which should render dark across the browser (per image) is:

HTML:

```
<div class="title-bar bar"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: -99;
}

.title-bar {
background-color: #000;
height: 150px;
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Any suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: try to check breaking point of your media queries.

Comment: Hi Umar Khan, I do not understand your suggestion. The title bar and footer bar should operate in the same way as in the DT browser based on the CSS, centered and colored bar across the browser. Can you elaborate pls. Thanks

Comment: i suppose that you are using css media quires to make your web site responsive so it display the content on your website as you want. if its not the case please provide more details or link to your web site so we can check

Comment: Hi Umar Khan no I am not doing it myself, this is a big commerce site and the CMS does it on the fly. There are two distinct CSS templates, one for mobile and one for the PC browser. On the iPad it defaults to the PC browser CSS (the mobile template looks radically different) and it does not resolve correctly per pic. The site address is http://kelvingroveequestrian.com.au. The other issue is the "Add This" buttons do not show on the iPad and this is std code from the Add This site, placed in the footer. It works OK on a DT/NB browser but not on iPad. Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

i think this meta tag divice width problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=800">
```

meta tag that i given in this meta tag in `width="800"`  put your website width instead of 800.
put this meta tag in head tag

eg.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width= your website width">
```